# Don't hide SweetAlert2 when another is launched

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am using SweetAlert2.  I want to show one alert behind another one, so that when the user clicks on the "OK" button, the other alert is shown behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many demos/examples on configuration docs: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#configuration
Add it as a Promise then to launch after the current SweetAlert.

```js
Swal.fire("1").then(x =>
  Swal.fire("2").then( x =>
    x.value && Swal.fire("3")))
    // check x.value, only fire "3" if button clicked
.then( x =>
  Swal.queue(["5","6","7"]))
  // you can also use queue to queue up alerts
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

Comment: Swal.queue works fine to acomplish that. Thanks a lot!